# JS array length returns 1 instead 0 when is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2016

Hi i have issue with my project. I received data in react component via props and when i try to check if length of those data are 0 i have problem to do that correctly. In amage bellow there are my logs. It shows there is nothing in themeParts array but length of that array is 0. I don't understand why is that doing? Also i can see in first row themeParts: Array(1) but after tags there is 0 so i don't know.. What it could be?

```
 render() {
        console.log(this.props.theme);
        console.log(this.props.theme.themeParts);
        console.log(this.props.theme.themeParts.length);
        <h5>{(this.props.theme.themeParts.length > 0)? 'true' : 'false'}</h5>
//This returns false but it should be true
}
```

[image: logs]

Edit:
This is how i am sending data. It has one more level but princip is same on level above this component. The function render which i send here before is render from Theme component. Maybe forEach doing something with data?

```
/**
 * Render themes for package
 * @return {[]}
 */
renderThemeList() {
    const items = [];
    this.props.package.themes.forEach((theme, key) => {
        items.push(<Theme key={key} theme={theme} hasOneTheme={(this.props.package.themes.length === 1)}/>);
    });
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you do console logging of an object, it immediately puts the log entry in your console, but at the time you actually evaluate the object, it may have changed since the time it was logged and now reflect something different. My guess is that the array has a length of 1 originally, but then it becomes an array of 0 by the time you drill down into it in your console. Is something mutating your data instead of immutably copying?

Comment: Yes i think it could be something like this but this data i am sending unchanged throught two components. Just using forEach on them. I try to put some code here in a while

Comment: I think the problem isn't in your component but in the _parent_ component; the object being passed through `this.props.package` is seemingly getting mutated.